# Where should I ask question about programming details?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a questions about how to start developing (programming) something, what tools should I use to this project, what should I know for this purpose itc. and I don't know where I should post them. Can someone help?

Comment: We don't really do that kind of thing, just Questions and Answers. If you want to learn something new there are usually plenty of books and tutorials available.

Comment: see [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Comment: @gnat That link is a very old feature request for a subjective site, which this is not. Also the answers do not answer this question, they provide opinions on whether or not a subjective site should exist, not guidelines on what to ask. It is strongly related, but not useful as a duplicate. If you must find a dupe I'm certain there are way better options. (Also I see you've closed a few other "where do I ask for general advice" questions as dupes of that in the past. I'm not sure why; it doesn't address that topic. You should probably break that pattern and find a better canonical question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed there are no sites like this. These sorts of broad, open-ended questions don't generally fit the model here well, and will not be well-received. They are not bad questions, this is just not the place to ask them.

Instead, use the other resources out there (books, internet searches / forums / tutorials / docs / browsing questions on SE sites / [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/) / etc., experimentation) to get yourself started. During your adventures, if you have specific questions or issues you run into, *then* [you can choose one of the programming sites here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in/129632#129632).

---

Also, a general design tip if you have a specific project: Start out by documenting your high level requirements, then do a rough actual design (often on paper if you have to), this will give you concrete criteria when searching for solutions and tools. Then you can take a more methodical approach and do your research on available technologies and piece together a collection of compatible solutions that allow you to implement all of your requirements. Implement rough prototypes of individual components and/or experiment with individual tools as you go if it helps you evaluate an option. Don't be afraid to try out a technology and discover that you don't care for it that much or that it has unexpected shortcomings, if you run into problems, keep track of why, this will help you search for better alternatives next time around.

And a general tip if you *don't* have a specific project: Make up a small project for yourself that is of interest to you. Then do the above.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I post this question on Reddit.